# Orthogonal complement of a subspace of constant functions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $X$ be a finite set and $F(X)$ the space of all functions $f:X \to \mathbb{R}.$ If $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle \colon F(X)\times F(X)\to \mathbb{R}, \langle f,g\rangle = \sum_{x\in X} f(x)g(x)$ defines an inner product and $V\subset F(X)$ is the subspace of all constant functions of $F(X)$ show that $V^\bot = \{ f\in F(X) \colon \sum_{x\in X} f(x) = 0 \}.$

I'm slightly confused about how to approach the problem. It seems that what  I would like to achieve is to show that for every $v \in V^\bot$ and every $f \in V$ I have that $\langle v,g\rangle=0$? Any hints would be appreciated. Another approach would probably be that I would indeed show that all vectors of $V^\bot$ would be orthogonal to the vectors of $V$ and then show that $V^\bot \subset V$ and $V \subset V^\bot$?

Comment: Your second approach sounds good to me. :)

Comment: But I feel like I'm assuming something I would need to show here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Let $\bf 1$ denote the constant $1$ function. Show that $V={\rm span}({\bf 1})$.
   So, $V^\perp=\{{\bf 1}\}^\perp$, i.e. $f\perp V\iff f\perp{\bf 1}$.
2. Calculate $\langle f,{\bf 1}\rangle$ for generic $f\in F(X)$.
3. Conclude.

Comment: I have that $\langle f,{\bf 1}\rangle = \sum_{x\in X} f(x){\bf 1} = \sum_{x\in X} f(x)$, but this doesn't seem to help in showing that the vectors would be orthogonal?

Comment: What is meant here by 'orthogonal'? Given an $f\in F(X)$, when will it be orthogonal to $\bf 1$?

Comment: When the inner product is $0$?

Comment: Yes yes, exactly. Just put the puzzles together.